# How would you get the output of a command as it's running when exec-ing in Go?

Tags: go, command, exec

So far I've seen a few different ways whereby you can easily execute a shell command in go and yield it's output.
However, there are a ton of commands that output while the program is still running, for example, `git clone ...`

If `git clone http://some.repo.git` is executed using something like:

`out, err := exec.Command("...").Output()`

There doesn't seem to be any output as it's running obviously. Or at least in my experiance that seems to be the case. Is there a simple way or pattern that can be implemented to show the live output of the command that is being ran?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get a pipe connected to the command's `stdout`:

```
cmd := exec.Command("...")

pipe, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
```

Then start the command:

```
err := cmd.Start()
```

and read its output (periodically ever so often):

```
b := make([]byte, 1024, 1024)

n, err := pipe.Read(b)

// b contains up to 1024 characters of cmd's output
```

in the end, and with a drained pipe (no output left in the pipe), call `Wait` to wait for the command to exit:

```
err := cmd.Wait()
```